# Lyx - How to save a template?

Tags: lyx, templates

How can I save a template using Lyx?
I know I can just save it somewhere and then copy and edit the file. But I want to use the `new from template` option in Lyx.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://wiki.lyx.org/Layouts/CreatingLayouts

Comment: Looks like the "templates" that are included with LyX is just normal .lyx-files with some dummy content. So just set up a document with whatever settings you need, and add and example author, title, sections, content, `<whatever>`, save the file, and you have yourself a new template.

Answer (score 1):

> But I want to use the new from template option in Lyx.

You can save your own file with dummy content in:

- the directory of the default templates, for example in my Linux is `/usr/share/lyx/templates`. But probably you will need root privileges to do this and ... be careful with the system updates!
- your own template directory. Go to menus <kbd>Tools</kbd> > <kbd>Preferences ...</kbd>  > <kbd>Paths</kbd> > <kbd>Documents templates</kbd> > <kbd>Browse...</kbd> to select one. Then, make this directory non writable if you want avoid accidental updates of the templates that you open frequently.

Answer (score 0):

As Torbjorn in the comment above says, there's no need to save the file as a template. Any Lyx file can be opened as a template.